# Does the converse to Kronecker's lemma hold?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, cesaro-summable

Odds are that this question has been answered already and even that the argument is not too complicated, but here it goes:

Assume that $(a_{k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of real numbers and $(b_{k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of positive numbers with $\lim_{n}b_{n}=\infty$.

*Can we infer from the hypothesis*
$$\sum_{k}a_{k}$$
*is* not *convergent that* 
$$\limsup_{n}|\frac{1}{b_{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}b_{k}|>0?$$
 In other words, *does the converse to Kronecker's lemma hold?*

For the purpose of my question, you can assume that $(a_{n})_{n}$ is positive and decreasing and that $b_{n}=n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $\displaystyle a_k=\frac{1}{k\log k}$ for $k\geq 2$, and say $a_1=10$;note that the series $a_k$ is divergent, and that $a_k$ is decreasing. Put $b_k=k$. We have 
$$\sum_{2}^n\frac{1}{\log k}\leq \frac{1}{\log 2}+\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log t}$$
Integrating by parts 
$$\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log t} =\frac{x}{\log x}-\frac{2}{\log 2}+\int_2^x \frac{dt}{(\log t)^2}$$

Now there exists $A$ such that for $t\geq A$, we have $\log t\geq 2$, and hence for $x\geq A$  $$\displaystyle \int_A^x\frac{dt}{(\log t)^2}\leq \frac{1}{2} \int_A^x\frac{dt}{\log t} $$
With some computations, this show that there exists a constant $c_1$ such that
$$\int_2^x \frac{dt}{\log t}\leq 2\frac {x}{\log x}+c_1$$
Now we get with a constant $c_2$
$$\frac{1}{b_n}\sum_{k=1}^n b_ka_k\leq \frac{2}{\log n}+\frac{c_2}{n}$$
and $\displaystyle \frac{1}{b_n}\sum_{k=1}^n b_ka_k \to 0$.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Actually for every $a_{n}\to 0$
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}\to 0$$
by Cesaro convergence. Thus it suffices to find (as you did) $a_{n}\to 0$ such that
$$\sum_{k}\frac{a_{k}}{k}$$
is divergent.