# Proving the converse of Kronecker's lemma?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If a series $\sum a_n$ is so constituted that for every positive monotone sequence $(p_n)$ tending to $+\infty$, the quotients $${p_0a_0+p_1a_1+\cdots p_na_n \over p_n\tag1} \to 0$$then $\sum a_n$ is convergent. There is a related question here [Converse for Kronecker's lemma on infinite series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3373448/converse-for-kroneckers-lemma-on-infinite-series). However the OP provides his answer which doesn't deal with the case $\liminf s_n = +\infty$, where $s_n = \sum_{n=0}^{k=n}a_k$. In his answer the OP proves the contrapositive: assuming that $\sum a_n$ is divergent, he constructs a non-decreasing $p_n$ sequence for which $1)$ does not hold. Can we also find a *strictly* monotone increasing sequence for which we obtain a contradiction? Different proofs are welcome.